# Find all elements with text string?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to remove all html-elements (tags) that contain a specific text-string. I have 2376 html-documents, all with different doctype standards. Some even don't have a doctype (might be irrelevant to this question).

So, I am looking for a text string that says "How to cite this paper", and I've found that it is enclosed within either a `<p>-tag`, `<h4>-tag` or a `<legend>-tag`.

The `<p>-tag` often looks like this,

```
<p style="text-align : center; color : Red; font-weight : bold;">How to cite this paper:</i></p>
```

The `<h4>-tag` often looks like this,

```
<h4>How to cite this paper:</h4>Antunes, P., Costa, C.J. &amp; Pino, J.A. (2006).
```

The `<legend>-tag` looks like this,

```
<legend style="color: white; background-color: maroon; font-size: medium; padding: .1ex .5ex; border-right: 1px solid navy; border-bottom: 1px solid navy; font-weight: bold;">How to cite this paper</legend>
```

The task at hand is to find these tags and remove them from the file, and then save the file again. I do have more tags to remove, but need some help understanding HAP and XPath, and how to locate specific tags based on their values or other unique data.

So far I have come up with this code in C#, it's a console application.
This is my Main (sorry for bad indentation),

```
//Variables
string Ext = "*.html";
string folder = @"D:\websites\dev.openjournal.tld\public\arkivet\";
IEnumerable<string> files = GetHTMLFiles(folder, Ext);
List<string> cite_files = new List<string>();            
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

//Loop to match all html-elements to query
foreach (var file in files)
{
 try
   {
      doc.Load(file);
      cite_files.Add(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h4[contains(., 'How to cite this paper')]").ToString()); 

     cite_files.Add(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[contains(., 'How to cite this paper')]").ToString());
   }                
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                //Counts numbers of hits and prints data to user
                int filecount = files.Count();
                int citations = cite_files.Count();            
                Console.WriteLine("Number of files scanned: " + filecount);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of citations: {0}", citations);

                // Program end
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close program....");
                Console.ReadKey();
```

And this is the private method that looks through directories for files,

```
//List all HTML-files recursively and return them to a list 
 public static IEnumerable<string> GetHTMLFiles(string directory, string Ext)
    {
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(directory, Ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }            
        return files;
    }
```

The unique thing seems to be "How to cite this paper" so I am trying to find all specific tags that contain these exact words, and then remove them. My Notepad shows that there should be 1094 files with this phrase, so I am trying to get them all. :)

Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html Agility Pack supports LINQ selectors, which is very convenient in this case. Given some HTML based on your example above:

```
var html =
@"<html><head></head><body>

<!-- selector match: delete these nodes -->
<p style='text-align: center; color: Red; font-weight: bold;'>How to cite this paper:</i></p>
<h4> How to cite this paper:</h4> Antunes, P., Costa, C.J. & amp; Pino, J.A. (2006).
<legend style='color: white; background-color: maroon; font-size: medium; padding: .1ex .5ex; border-right: 1px solid navy; border-bottom: 1px solid navy; font-weight: bold;'>How to cite this paper </legend>
<div><p><i><b>How to cite this paper (NESTED)</b></i></p></div>

<!-- no match: keep these nodes -->
<p>DO NOT DELETE - How to cite</p>
<h4>DO NOT DELETE - cite this paper:</h4>
<legend>DO NOT DELETE</legend>

</body></html>";
```

You can create a collection of tags that should be searched, select matching nodes, and then and remove them like this:

```
var tagsToDelete = new string[] { "p", "h4", "legend" };
var nodesToDelete = new List<HtmlNode>();

var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (var tag in tagsToDelete)
{
    nodesToDelete.AddRange(
        from searchText in document.DocumentNode.Descendants(tag)
            where searchText.InnerText.Contains("How to cite this paper")
            select searchText
    );
}

foreach (var node in nodesToDelete) node.Remove();

document.Save(OUTPUT);
```

With the the following result:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<!-- XPath match: delete these nodes -->

 Antunes, P., Costa, C.J. & amp; Pino, J.A. (2006).

<div></div>

<!-- no match, keep these nodes -->
<p>DO NOT DELETE - How to cite</p>
<h4>DO NOT DELETE - cite this paper:</h4>
<legend>DO NOT DELETE</legend>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. Much appreciated. Now, what if I want to remove the nodes as well? As I don't want empty nodes, I would rather delete InnerText and node. Or do node.Remove() actually delete the node as well? I'll give this a run in the morning.

Again, thanks for a really good answer. :)

Comment: @ChristerJohansson - the sample code above does remove the matching `p`, `h4`, and `legend` nodes, as shown in the result. :)

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll tinker around with this tomorrow then. Again, thank you. :)

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. It does not return anything to the nodesToDelete list. I am using VS 2017 Community. I tried doing a foreach to see if there was content in the list, but it's empty. VS does not indicate any errors. I made a fiddle of it, https://dotnetfiddle.net/p70zWr

Comment: My example was loading an HTML `string`, but you're loading _**file paths**_. So you need to use `document.Load(file)`,  **not** `document.LoadHtml(file);`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I feel like complete idiot now. I had to change to `document.Load(@file)` in order to get data into the List. I get 1064 hits out of 1094 from Notepad. I have to refine the search a bit more, or run them multiple times. This snippet runs at almost 1 Gb of ram... :O) 

Thanks for helping! Much appreciated!